# WPF window not stopping timer/closing and lowering RAM usage

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, wpf-controls

Hey all I have been trying a lot of ways to correct my issue here with my WPF program. WPF is a great technology for making really nice apps but its odd-ball commands that differ from that of a **WinForm** gets me upset sometimes.

I have my main window load up and the event that opens the MoviePosters window:

```
namespace WpfApplication49
{
    public partial class firstWindow : Window
    {
        public static bool exitLoading = false;
        public static bool loadedMovies  = false;
        public static MoviePosters MP;

....[more code within this area]

    private void myControl1_Click(object sender, myClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.my.Tag.ToString().Contains("movieIcon"))
        {
            if (!loadedMovies)
            {
                MP = new MoviePosters();
                MP.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MP.Show();
            }
        }

....[more code within this area]

        this.Topmost = false;
    }

....[more code within this area]

}
```

I currently am loading up a **watchMovie.xaml** by this means from my **MoviePosters.xaml** window:

```
namespace WpfApplication49
{
    public partial class MoviePosters : Window
    {
        static watchingMovie MW;

    ....[more code within this area]

        private void myControl1_Click(object sender, myClickEventArgs e)
        {
            MW = new watchingMovie((string)e.my.Tag.ToString())
            MW.Show();
        }

    ....[more code within this area]
    }
}
```

That above loads up the window just fine. However, the issue is when I close this window and return back to the original window, it still has it in memory and the timer is still active!

The code for the close of the watchingMovie.xaml:

```
namespace WpfApplication49
{
    public partial class watchingMovie : Window
    {
        public readonly DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

        public watchingMovie(String movie)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            passedMovie = movie;
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            this.Topmost = true;
        }

    ....[more code within this area]

        public void Exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ME.Stop();
            ME.Close();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            timer.Stop();
            this.Close();
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan _duration = ME.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
            TimeSpan remaining = _duration.Subtract(ME.Position);

            if (!isDragging)
            {
                seekBar.Value = ME.Position.TotalSeconds;
                currentposition = seekBar.Value;
                lblMovieTime.Content = remaining.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
            }

            var totalTime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", (_duration.Hours * 60) + _duration.Minutes, _duration.Seconds);

        
            var currentTime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", (remaining.Hours * 60) + remaining.Minutes, remaining.Seconds);

            TimeSpan diff = remaining - _duration;
        }

 ....[more code within this area]

    }
}
```

From the start of the **firstWindow.xaml** the RAM starts out at **~59.0 MB**. When it gets to the **MoviePoster** window the RAM used is **~105.4 MB**. When I load up the **watchingMovie** window it goes up to **~145.0 MB**. When I exit the **watchingMovie** window (with the this.Close()) it takes me back to the **MoviePoster** window and the RAM then is **~143.0 MB**. And every time I load the **watchingMovie** window the more the RAM usage goes up!

So...

- Shouldn't the ram be back to around **~105 MB** like it was
  *before* loading the **watchingMovie** window since I closed that window?
- I don't understand why the timer is still counting the minutes of
  the movie - you know, since it should have stopped it once the
  window itself had closed?

Here is a short animated GIF to show from the start of my program to the exit of the **watchingMovie** window.

[image]

**update #1**

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned about RAM usage, that's quite normal. So you shouldn't call `GC.Collect`. The timer still running is a problem though. Is `Exit_Click` actually being called?

Comment: If you expect by calling GC.Collect will remove the current instance of a class - no, it won't. It can only collect objects not referenced any more. For example your variable `static watchingMovie MW` will keep a reference to the last instance of your watchingMovie window. The timer also keeps a reference to your window by the event handler timer_Tick. You made the timer public, so it is unclear what else you are doing with it. But you are already using the diagnostic tool, simply make a snapshot before opening and after closing your window and examine the kept references.

Comment: Stop the timer first, remove its handler, wait 200ms, close the MediaElement, close the Window. Remove the `public` modifier from the timer and remove any reference to this timer, if any, from any other place. If you misuse a timer, you have the same effect both in WinForms and WPF.

Comment: Where do you destroy your timer? Also, event handlers for clicks?! People moved on from those. Is ME, a media element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling GC in this case is completely pointless.
Since the timer continues to work for you, it means that some references to objects remain, and as long as there are these references, the GC will not collect these objects.

In the Window close event, you need to stop the timer and clear all static links.
Something like this:

```cs
    public watchingMovie(String movie)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Closed += OnWindowClosed;

        passedMovie = movie;
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        this.Topmost = true;
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        // Some Code
    }

    private void OnWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Tick -= timer_Tick;
        ME.Stop();
        ME.Close();
        ME = null;
    }
```

```cs
        private void myControl1_Click(object sender, myClickEventArgs e)
        {
            MW = new watchingMovie((string)e.my.Tag.ToString());
            MW.Closed += (_, __) => MW = null;
            MW.Show();
        }
```

```cs
    public firstWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Closed += (_, __) => MP?.Close();
    }

    private void myControl1_Click(object sender, myClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.my.Tag.ToString().Contains("movieIcon"))
        {
            if (!loadedMovies)
            {
                MP = new MoviePosters();
                MP.Closed += (_, __) => MP = null;
                MP.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MP.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

**P.S.** I strongly advise you to completely abandon static members (fields and properties) that store dynamically created objects.
Static members can only be used to store references to objects that must exist for the duration of the application session.
Such objects should not be closed, destroyed until the session ends.

Comment: Followed your suggestions and the timer does seem to stop on exit but I am getting an error on the timer itself now. See updated OP. Though taking out the **ME = null;** fixes this but wanted to make sure that really wasn't needed?

Comment: I cannot accurately judge the work of your application since the shown code is not enough for this.
Zeroing ME, MP, MW is necessary if, after closed the timer is closed and/or after the Window is closed, these instances are no longer needed and you need to clear the memory from them.
The screenshot of the error shows that you continue to contact ME. And you must decide for yourself how it will be correct for the logic of your program: do not destroy ME or do not refer to ME if it already (or yet) not .